# Função fatorial em C não retorna o resultado

Tags: c, funções, return

O que há de errado em meu código?

```
int fatorial (int n, int num, int fat) 
{
    if(num >= 0)
    {
        fat = 1;
        n = num;

        while(n > 0)
        {
            fat *= n;     //FATORIAL = FATORIAL*N
            n--;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Explique os parâmetros da função, por favor. Por quê existem três, sendo que dois dele você altera o valor dentro da função sem passar a variável por referência (que nem faz sentido, ao meu ver)? Aliás, a função não possui retorno.

Comment: Você não precisa passar uma " variável " pra guardar o valor fatorial ( até porque se fosse fazer isso teria de ser um ponteiro e como é fatorial você normalmente deveria apenas dar um return no valor ), você só precisa fazer um if / else ' se ' o número for menor 2 return 1 e no ' else ' você chama a função multiplicando a mesma por ela mesma menos um.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função não está retornando nada, seja o valor válido ou não. Usei o -1 para indicar erro.

Além disso, está usando parâmetros completamente desnecessários: `fat` pode ser local e `n` simplesmente não precisa nem mesmo como variável local.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fatorial(int num) {
    if (num >= 0) {
        int fat = 1;
        while (num > 0) {
            fat *= num;
            num--;
        }
        return fat;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", fatorial(0));
    printf("%d\n", fatorial(1));
    printf("%d\n", fatorial(5));
    printf("%d\n", fatorial(-5));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/D0qKAU). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/glvtznhi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/Factorial.c).

Comment: Posso fazer isso na main:

Comment: int main(){
    int n,num,fat;
    printf("ESTE POGRAMA CALCULA N FATORIAL = N!\n");
    printf("Digite um valor para ser calculado: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    printf("\n\tO fatorial de %d = %d\n\n",fatorial);
    //printf("%d!=%d\n",num,fat);

    //else printf("O calculo do fatorial se aplica somene aos numeros naturais.\n");
system("pause");   //pausa o sistema
}

Comment: @ThiagoFerreira pode, claro, basta testar se retornou -1. Embora dê para fazer fatorial de negativos.

Comment: Não existe fatorial de negativo, porque quero que o usuário digite o fatorial e exiba na tela pra isso preciso chamar a função não é? Só que está dando erro na main.

Comment: @ThiagoFerreira eu respondi o que estava na sua pergunta. Se tem outro problema que não está na pergunta você deve abrir uma nova pergunta colocando o código que está dando erro e dando o máximo de informações possível para podermos ajudar melhor. Veja como fazer um [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Por padrão, o C retorna 0 para uma função sem return, por exemplo a função `int teste() { }` não tem erro de compilação, porque a linguagem C retorna zero como um return padrão. Então, a função se torna:

```
int teste() {
  return 0; // código adicionado pelo compilador C
}
```

Na tua função:

```
int fatorial (int n, int num, int fat) 
{
    if(num >= 0)
    {
        fat = 1;
        n = num;

        while(n > 0)
        {
            fat *= n;     //FATORIAL = FATORIAL*N
            n--;
        }
    }
    return 0; //adicionado pelo compilador
}
```

Comment: e a main como fica? o usuário digitando o número de 1 até 10 informando o fatorial?

Answer (score -4):

```
// A página:

// https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272152/c-como-calcular-o-fatorial-de-um-numero

// apresenta muitas maneiras de calcular o fatorial em C:

// Maneira 1 (comentários meus):

/*   scanf("%d", &n) ;
 *   for(fat = 1; n > 1; n = n - 1) // ciclo mal concebido
 *   {                              // difícil de perceber
 *       fat = fat * n;
 *   }
 */

// Maneira 2 (comentários meus):

/* #include<stdio.h>
 *
 * int fat, n;   // NUNCA USAR VARIÁVEIS GLOBAIS
 *
 * int main()
 * {
 *   scanf("%d", &n) ;
 *
 *   for(fat = 1; n > 1; n = n - 1) // mesmo disparate
 *   {
 *       fat = fat * n; // para quê as {} ?
 *   }
 *
 *   printf("\n%d", fat); // seria %d\n ?
 *   return 0;
 * }
 */

// Maneira 3 (comentários meus):

/* unsigned long long fatorial( int n ) // unsigned long long parece boa ideia!
 * {                                    // porque os fatorias são números mto grandes
 *     unsigned long long f = 1;        // no entanto, para o meu compilador
                                        // um unsigned long long usa 4bytes
                                        // e um int também usa 4bytes
                                        // o que quer dizer que (ignorando a questão do sinal)
                                        // TANTO FAZ USAR UM COMO OUTRO
                                        // para quê complicar?
 *
 *     while( n > 0 )
 *         f *= n--;   // notação supercriptica
 *
 *     return f;
 * }
 */

// Maneira 4 (comentários meus):

/* unsigned long long fatorial( int n )
 * {
 *     unsigned long long f = 1;
 *     for( ; n > 0; f *= n-- ); // ciclo completamente idiota e críptico
 *     return f;
 * }
 */

 // Maneira 5 (sem comentários...):

/* unsigned long long fatorial( int n )
 * {
 *     static const unsigned long long fat[21] = { 1ULL, 1ULL, 2ULL, 6ULL, 24ULL, 120ULL, 720ULL, 5040ULL,
 *                                                 40320ULL, 362880ULL, 3628800ULL, 39916800ULL, 479001600ULL,
 *                                                 6227020800ULL, 87178291200ULL, 1307674368000ULL,
 *                                                 20922789888000ULL, 355687428096000ULL, 6402373705728000ULL,
 *                                                 121645100408832000ULL, 2432902008176640000ULL };
 *     return fat[n];
 * } */

// Maneira 6 (comentários meus):

/* #include <stdio.h>
 *                          // um double são 8bytes, e um int que são 4bytes
                            // contudo um double é para guardar números reais!!!
                            // NÃO SERVE !
 * double fatorial(int n);  // declara a fc que vai definir abaixo da main
 *                          // questão de estilo
 * int main(void){
 *     int num = 3;
 *     printf("Fatorial de %d = %.0lf",num,fatorial(num)); // %.0lf está MAL
 *     return 0;
 * }
 *
 * double fatorial(int n){
 *     double fat;          // gordo duplo ?
 *     if ( n <= 1 )        // implementação recursiva (não tem vantagem neste caso)
 *         return (1);      // porquê o () ?
 *     else{                // porquê as {} se em cima não levou?
 *        return n * fatorial(n - 1);
 *     }
 * } */

 // E finalmente, COMO EU ACHO QUE SE DEVE FAZER

 #include <stdio.h>

 // versão int (4 bytes : 31 bits + sinal)
 int fatorial(int n)
 {
    int f=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) f=f*i; // ciclo OK! Notação normal...
    return f;                    // poderia usar f*=i que não perdia legibilidade
 }
 // 3 linhas de código claro como água...

 // versão unsigned long int (8 bytes : 64 bits)
 unsigned long int fatoriall(int n)
 {
    unsigned long int f=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) f=f*i; // ciclo OK! Notação normal...
    return f;                    // poderia usar f*=i que não perdia legibilidade
 }
 // 3 linhas de código claro como água...

 // versão recursiva
 unsigned long int fatorialr(int n)
 {
    if (n==0) return 1;                // Até quem não sabe o que é a recursividade
    else      return n*fatorialr(n-1); // percebe esta função, de tão clara que é!
 }
 // 2 linhas de código claro como água...

 int main()
 {
    // teste às funções
    printf("%d! = %d\n" ,12,fatorial (12));

    // fatorial(13) já não cabe num int (4 bytes : 31 bits + sinal)
    // fatorial(12) =  479001600
    // fatorial(13) = 6227020800
    // 2^31-1       = 2147483647 (maior número possível em 4 bytes (31 bits + sinal))

    printf("%d! = %lu\n",20,fatoriall(20)); // %lu para unsigned long int
    printf("%d! = %lu\n",20,fatorialr(20));

    // fatorial(21) já não cabe num unsigned long int (8 bytes : 64 bits)
    // fatorial(20) =  2432902008176640000
    // fatorial(21) = 51090942171709440000
    // 2^64-1       = 18446744073709551615 (maior número possível em 8 bytes)

    getchar();
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).