# C - como calcular o fatorial de um numero?

Tags: c, for

To tentando mas não estou conseguindo,
por exemplo:
o fatorial de 5 é dado por 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1.

Tem que desenvolver um programa que calcule o fatorial de um número dado como entrada.(usando for )

Comment: Compartilha o que você já tentou em forma de código

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pega o Valor que vai servi de referencia no caso estou usando o **N**
 Logo após criaremos um **FOR** onde irá se repetir até que o **N** seja igual a **1**, fazendo dentro do corpo do **FOR** o calculo do Fatorial

```
  scanf("%d", &n) ;

  for(fat = 1; n > 1; n = n - 1)
  {      
      fat = fat * n;
  }
```

Ficando desde jeito no final:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fat, n;

int main()
{
  scanf("%d", &n) ;

  for(fat = 1; n > 1; n = n - 1)
  {
      fat = fat * n;
  }

  printf("\n%d", fat);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você se importa de explicar o que está acontecendo aí? Como está não parece que vai ajudar muito o AP - ele não entendeu como fazer, e então tem um programa pronto com "faça desse jeito". Talvez pudesse ser mais didático.

Answer (score 2):

Segue uma função (usando `while`) bastante simples capaz de calcular fatorial de um número `n`:

```
unsigned long long fatorial( int n )
{
    unsigned long long f = 1;

    while( n > 0 )
        f *= n--;

    return f;
}
```

Se a ideia é mesmo usar um laço `for`:

```
unsigned long long fatorial( int n )
{
    unsigned long long f = 1;
    for( ; n > 0; f *= n-- );
    return f;
}
```

Uma outra forma de resolver o problema sem nenhum tipo de loop é usando uma tabela pré-calculada contendo todos os `21` possíveis resultados que caibam dentro de um `unsigned long long`:

```
unsigned long long fatorial( int n )
{
    static const unsigned long long fat[21] = { 1ULL, 1ULL, 2ULL, 6ULL, 24ULL, 120ULL, 720ULL, 5040ULL,
                                                40320ULL, 362880ULL, 3628800ULL, 39916800ULL, 479001600ULL,
                                                6227020800ULL, 87178291200ULL, 1307674368000ULL,
                                                20922789888000ULL, 355687428096000ULL, 6402373705728000ULL,
                                                121645100408832000ULL, 2432902008176640000ULL };
    return fat[n];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra alternativa é usar uma chamada **recursiva**, eis o exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double fatorial(int n);
int main(void){
    int num = 3;
    printf("Fatorial de %d = %.0lf",num,fatorial(num));
    return 0;
}

double fatorial(int n){
    double fat;
    if ( n <= 1 )
        return (1);
    else{
       return n * fatorial(n - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pronto @MIguel código alterado

Comment: O corpo do seu `fatorial(int)` pode ser simplificado para: `return n < 2 ? 1 : n * fatorial(n - 1);`. Outra, por que está retornando `double`?

Comment: Pode sim, esse foi só um exemplo.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi, retornar `double` realmente não faz sentido desse jeito que está disposto.